# When setting a URL for img tag the image don't refresh- only after refreshing the page

Tags: knockout.js

I am pretty new to KnouckOut, there is a file dialog where the user can choose an image, after he select an image, there is a button "save" after the user click the "save" button > the dialog is getting closed and the image is not showing in the place for it.

The issue (bug) that i am trying to solve > only when i **refresh the page the image is getting shown**.

This is from the `view.html`

```
 <div data-bind="visible: thumbnailVisible">
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: computedThumbnailUrl }, css: { 'cms-fileupload-thumbnail': isExternal }" alt="Image preview"/>
        </div>
```

This is from the `viewmodel.js`

```
    define(['application'],
function(cms) {
// code...
 this.computedThumbnailUrl = ko.computed(
                function () {
                    return this.thumbnailVisible()
                        ? this.isExternal()
                            ? this.thumbnailUrl()
                            : baseUrl + this.thumbnailUrl() + '&var=' + this.thumbnailTimestamp().unix()
                        : null;
                }, this);

// code...

 fileUpload.prototype.browseS3Bucket = function() {
        var self = this;
        cms.showDialog('widgets/fileUpload/s3Bucket', {
            bucketName: this.s3BucketName
        }).then(function(obj) {
            if (obj) {
                var s3Object = {
                    'bucketName': self.s3BucketName,
                    'key': obj.key,
                    'size': obj.size,
                    'url': obj.url
                };
                self.value().s3Object = s3Object;
                self.downloadUrl(obj.url);
                self.thumbnailUrl(obj.url);
                self.fileSize(obj.size);
                self.value.valueHasMutated();
            }
        });

// code...
}
```

This from the `Product.js` page:

```
define(['application', 'dataservices/dataservice.webservice'],
function (cms, dataservice) {
 // code...
 viewModel.prototype.save = function () {
        cms.closeDialog(this, this.selectedObject());
    };
// code...
}
```

Is there something that i am missing?

Comment: Can you provide an example that fully duplicates the problem?

Comment: no, sorry- this is a part of a large application - i described what i thought was necessary

Comment: If you bind to `computedThumbnailUrl` using `text` binding, do you see the correct url?

Comment: i update my question, as you can see- my question is when `viewModel.prototype.save` is called > i want to update the image (url) and so.. how can i call from `viewModel.prototype.save` function in `Product.js` to a function in `viewmodel.js` ?

Comment: Your code doesn't show that `thumbnailUrl` gets changed anywhere. You need to update its value.

Comment: I edited the post, `thumbnailUrl` get up-dated in `fileUpload.prototype.browseS3Bucket`, the problem with that (i think), when calling `self.value.valueHasMutated();` the values are saved for `self` only cause when i debug it and i hit a break-point more further on the way `fileSize` is null. there is a reason for this?

Comment: Is there only one `thumbnailUrl`? You're updating in `fileUpload`. Is `computedThumbnailUrl` also in `fileUpload`?